# How to read Wildfly resteasy deserialization error from client?

Tags: jboss, jax-rs, resteasy, wildfly, java-ee-7

My Wildfly resteasy service is working fine, or was until I made a code change. No big deal, now I'm getting a deserialization error: `"Problem deserializing 'setterless' property ..."`

My question is whether there is anyway to get an error message in the client. I'm getting a Status of 400, and I can test that, but I'd like to get any message if possible. Any ideas?

If I get an error in the user code, I can set an error message in the header, but since there is a deserialization problem, the server is throwing a error before getting to any user code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [`ExceptionMapper`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html) to handle the response returned to the client. JAX-RS has an exception hierarchy that will map to different responses and status codes. 400 in JAX-RS is a [`BadRequestException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/BadRequestException.html). So you could do something like

```
@Provider
public class BadRequestExceptionMapper
                      implements ExceptionMapper<BadRequestException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(BadRequestException e) {
        Response response = Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                .entity("Sorry I forgot to implement a Setter").build();
        return response;
    }  
}
```

This isn't a very great example, because `BadRequestException` is thrown for many other reasons, than just forgetting a setter (or deserialization), but it demonstrates how you can intercept the response after the exception is thrown.

- See [RestEasy Exception Handling](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html/ExceptionHandling.html#ExceptionMappers)
- [Jersey User Guider has a better explanation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e5207)
- See [Exception Hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26798284/2587435)