# REST (Jersey): Return an error in the response in a method with return type other than Response

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have some REST methods for a web application, that are called via ajax. Most of them return lists of DTOs, so the return types of the methods are declared as List, producing a JSON from the list.
All is working OK, but now I need, in one of the methods, to make the difference between an empty list (which is valid for the front-end) and a list that comes as null.

This is the simple code of the method in question:

```
@GET
@Path("getComparedItems")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<ItemDTO> getComparedItems() {
    List<ItemDTO> comparedItems = itemsService.getComparedItemsDTOList();
    //List populated with updated/new items.
    //If empty: no changes
    //If null: error, probably obtaining external data
    if (comparedItemsPlayers != null) {
        return comparedItems;
    } else {
        //TODO...
    }
}
```

So, about the TODO block, which should return an error:

I could return null (which becomes a 204 No content) and handle that code in the ajax call, but I prefer to avoid this, as the ajax call is only handling 5xx errors currently (and because 204 is not an error btw).
I could throw a WebApplicationException, or other, so the front-end becomes aware of the 500 error, but I don't want an Exception in the rest method just for the heck of it, or at least no without building the error explicitly.

So, the thing I was trying to do is to return a Response with somenthing like:

```
return Response.serverError().build();
```

Doing that, forces me to change the return type of the method to Response.

Just for curiosity, I wonder if there is a way of mantaining the return type as List, and build a Response with the Error that is compatible with that. I read about it, and find some ways to put the list in the Response as a generic entity:

```
GenericEntity<List<ItemDTO>> respEntity =
        new GenericEntity<List<ItemDTO>>(comparedItems) {};
return Response.serverError().entity(respEntity).build();
```

But (as I should notice) the types are still incompatible. So, how could I return the list as List but specifying the Server Error? Is there a way or the method return type must be changed in these cases, no matter what?

Thank you.

Comment: WebApplicationException accepts a Response as a constructor argument. There are also a bunch of speciliazed subclasses of WebApplicationException that return specifci error codes, like ServerErrorException or IntrernalServerErrorException. [See this list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26798284/2587435)

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Didn't notice that (Response) constructor, and it is just the kind of thing I was looking for. So thank you very much.